# What Oauth2 flow to choose for this particular situation?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a single page app (call it `Collector`) on my server and would like my users to have a customizable list of links like :

`facebook.com/get_my_latest_posts_about_cats
github.com/get_my_comments_for_repo_LinuxKernel
anynews.com/get_my_soccer_news`

They can add new/remove links into their link dialog box every time.

So what I am trying to do is to relieve the user of the pain to login every time in order to get data from the `facebook,github,news ...` server.

Of course, the first time the user clicks on any of his links he will receive the respective login page of the link (e.g. `facebook.com/get_my_latest_posts_about_cats` -> `facebook.com/login`) but afterwards I'll use their access token along with refresh token stored in my `Collector database` so that they won't have to write their pass and username every next time.

My question :

(Please tell me if at least it makes any sense, so that I don't get any false ideas about how this works)

- I don't know what flow should I implement my `Collector` web app because I'm doing this for the first time, and the whole `authentication process` is also new for me, so which one actually would fit my needs ?
- I thought about [user agent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm) flow, becaue I don't think I want to store the `client_secret` in my `Collector` database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single page apps, it's usually the best to use implicit flow. This way, the access token gets just to the frontend part - stays in the browser, it doesn't get to your Collector backend, because the access token is located in the hash part (behind "#") of  the redirect URL from an OAuth2 server. Then you can store the access token in browser's SessionStorage to survive reloads. But if you use this flow, you must use HTTPS, otherwise it's not secure (the access token is transferred through an insecure channel).

Maybe you will want to get new tokens before current ones expire. It's usually done be using iframes, but it depends on a concrete OAuth2 server implementation. You can check http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html for OpenId Connect (which is an OAuth2 extension).

Comment: Thanks you for your time ! a lot of newbie questions arise when doing a thing for the first time.

Comment: Yes, OAuth2 can be quite a challenge if you need to make decisions without having much experience with it.

Comment: One more thing though, if I implement the implicit flow , the first time my user would like to receive his facebook posts then my js script would make a request to the facebook server, telling it that it needs the login page and in this request that I made lies the client_id, which is the id I got when I registered my `Collector` Web App on the facebook dev website. So I don't need any changes in my backend `Collector` code  ? 
If I got any of it wrong , please let me know :)

Comment: I haven't been working with the Facebook, but I think it's correct as you wrote it - the client_id is the ID of your registered application and you pass it in the URL when requesting authentication. Later, you should use just your JavaScript codes to communicate with Facebook, so no backend changes needed.